# Is it possible to add a JSTL forEach loop into an HTML Datalist?

Tags: javascript, html, jsp, spring-boot, jstl

In my Spring application, a user can save an `Address Object` which has two string variables an `address` and an `addressnickname`. The user can then save this object to a list of `Address Objects`. The `address` and `addressnickname` values are stored in a MySQL table via an AJAX Query sent to a Spring Boot Controller.

A debug in the controller, (as well as actually looking at the table in the MySQL cmd.exe) will show that the object successfully saves to the user's list of `Address Objects`.

Now I would like to pass each address object's `address`(where `address` equals an something like "123 fake street") and `addressnickname` (where `addressnickname` will equal something like "My House") to an [HTML Datalist](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) so a user can pick a saved location as their destination in a route planner in a google map or enter an address that isn't saved. Something like the screenshot below.

[image: Screenshot of proposed datalist]

The datalist above has been hardcoded like so:

```
<datalist id="places">
<option value = "123 Fake St, Dublin, Ireland">Home</option>
</datalist>
```

But is it possible to produce the same result as the screenshot by passing each object from the list instead? I've tried the following approach but with no luck.

```
 <datalist id="places">
   <c:forEach var="o" items="${savedAdresses}">
        <option value=<c:out value="${o.address}><c:out value="${o.addressnickname}" /></option>
   </c:forEach>
 </datalist>
```

P.S to keep the question concise I've left out the code from the controller, User Object, and Address Object Classes, but should they be required to answer the question I'm on standby to include them. Thank You!

**Edit** Adding in the saveAddress() method from the Controller Class

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/saveAddress", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
public @ResponseBody String saveAddressToUser(Address address, 
                                              @RequestParam("address") String address, 
                                             @RequestParam("addressnickname") String addressnickname) {

      // Authenticates the current logged in user
      Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String username = loggedInUser.getName(); // Authentication for 

      // Saves address to MySQL DB, and gets the logged in user profile from the DB
      addressRepository.save(address);
      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

      //Debug to show username of user, and the String address, and addressnickname variables successfully passing into the controller
      System.out.println(username + " just saved Address + "|called: " + address + "|nickname: " + addressnickname);

      // Adds the address object to the User's List of Address Object 
      user.addAddress(address);

      // Updates the user information
      userRepository.save(user);

    return "welcome";
}
```

User Object Variables

```
private Long id;
private String username;
private String password;
private String passwordConfirm;
private List<Area> savedAreas;
private List<Address> savedAddress; <-- List Of addresses the user saves address object to
```

Comment: It might be useful to see the controller tier code as well.  In your controller, are you making the list of `Address Object`s available to your JSP?  If it looks like you are, you might want try the following to debug: 1. Ensure the list has items.  2. Try displaying the list in the JSP in a very generic way to make sure it's available as expected (e.g. use those similar `<c:out>` tags to write `address` and `addressnickname` inside of a `<p>` somewhere on your page with no special formatting).

Comment: Hey @GoldDragonTSU I followed your debug advice and managed to fix it perfectly. Thank you. If you want to put up an answer I'd be happy to upvote it!

Comment: Excellent.  Glad you got it worked out.  Since I didn't come up with the actual answer and therefore am not 100% certain of the solution, I won't post an answer.  However, you may certainly [Self-Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) in case it helps someone with a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the debug advice from @GoldDragonTSU I realised I had forgotten to add another method in the controller that actually printed the list to a JSP page. The method in the Controller above saved the data to a list but there was nothing to actually print the list. I added the following method and configured the mapping correctly.

```
// Added the org.springframework.ui.Model as a method parameter for
// use in passing Addresses from this Controller method to the JSP View
@RequestMapping(value = "/addressCheckerPage", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String addressChecker(@Valid Addresses addresses, BindingResult bindingResult, Model model) {

     Authentication loggedInUser = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
      String username = loggedInUser.getName(); // Authentication for 

      addressesRepository.save(addresses);
      User user = userRepository.findByUsername(username);

      List<Addresses> savedAddresses = user.getSavedAddresses();
      for (int i = 0; i < savedAddresses.size(); i++) {
          // Do work with a user's individual saved addresses
      }

      // Make the user's saved address list available to the JSP:
      model.addAttribute("savedAddresses ", savedAddresses );

    return "addressChecker";
}
```

Comment: One final observation related to the code itself: while the user's saved address list (`savedAddresses`) is correctly added to the model for use by the JSP (`model.addAttribute(...);`), it looks like that's happening inside of a `for` loop, repeated for each individual address.  Since you aren't performing any operations on the individual addresses and you just want to add the entire list for front-end usage, it would be more efficient to make the `model.addAttribute(...);` call only once, outside of the `for` loop.  I'll make a few edits to reflect that, but good work overall figuring it out.